# Interpreting Pearson and Deviance residual graphs

Tags: logistic, generalized-linear-model, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, deviance

Using a generalised linear model and predicted probabilities, I have been able to plot the Pearson residuals and Deviance residuals. I did this in order to have goodness of fit measures for the model.[image: This is the Pearson residuals graph][image: This is the Deviance residuals graph]

The first plot is the Pearson and the second is the Deviance.

I am not sure how I should interpret each of these plots in order to conclude that they either point towards a good fit or they are not a good fit.